# How do you use Selenium to execute javascript within a frame?

Tags: java, javascript, testing, iframe, selenium

I have a page (index.html) which has a frame:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="otherPage.html" />
</body>
</html>
```

And the otherPage.html has the contents:

```
<html>
<head><link src="jquery-min.js" type="text/javascript" /></head>
<body><div id="main">Contents</div></body>
</html>
```

I am attempting to use the following selenium code on index.html:

```
selenium.open("index.html");
selenium.selectFrame("//iframe");
selenium.getEval("window.jQuery('div[id=main]')");
```

However this fails miserably. It says that the jQuery object doesn't exist.

If I attempt to execute the selenium test on the otherPage like so:

```
selenium.open("otherPage.html");
selenium.getEval("window.jQuery('div[id=main]')");
```

everything is hunky dory.

Right now this is pseudo code, if people want me to make it compile I'll do that and put it on github.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Selenium stores the Window Object within its own object so it can manipulate it better. Once you move to the frame it should be like this.

```
selenium.getEval("var window = this.browserbot.getUserWindow();window.jQuery('div[id=main]')");
```

And that should work for you

I have a tutorial on my site for this type of situation [here](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/Selenium_JavaScript.htm)

Comment: any idea how to do it from selenium IDE? window returns [object XPCNativeWrapper [object Window]] that does not have jQuery(long time after page is loaded).

Comment: Scores high on google when I was looking to do this in the IDE. Command is assertEval the Target is the script (make sure if you use jQuery to reference it from window so it's window.$("...) The value is the value it returns.

Answer (score 11):

You can use :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("javascript:sendEvent('play');");
```

Comment: This is the way to do it with Selenium 2 webdriver

Comment: Selenium type is not mentioned in question.